# JQuery Datatables Filtering a column with nested Object data (object in array)

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my JSON I have a nested Object data as array and Object. It looks like that:

```
"contentVMlist":[
            {
               "dbContID":3,
               "dbContType":2,
            },
            {
               "dbContID":1,
               "dbContType":1,
            }
```

with `"aoColumns: [ { "data": "contentVMlist.[ ].dbContType"} ]"`  i get the data into the table. 
It shows like this in the table column "2 1".

with

```
this.api().columns([9]).every(function () {
var column = this;
else if (column[0] == 9) {
var select2 = $('<select> </select>') // the select is not so short i just shortened it now
                            .appendTo($('#dbContType')).on('change', function () {
                                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                            $(this).val()
                                        );
column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
});
```

if "contentVMlist" only has 1 entry, everything works fine. But if there are 2 or more entries (like "1 3" or " 1 3 2") it cannot see the entries as single occurences. it works if the select would be "1 3 2", but the user only wants to chose one and then all with that type show up (if there is more than one it should show up too)

How can I get this done? 
I tried a few different things that didnt work.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Have a list of all dbContType values in a select list?

Comment: @balint i have a dropdown-filter with the dbContTypes. The user can filter the datatable with that filter

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to iterate through this nested array:

```
var contentVMlist= []; // get a reference to the nested array
jQuery.each(contentVMlist, function() {
    console.log(this.dbContType); // check it
    selectObj.appendTo("<option>"+this.dbContType+"</option>");
});
```

Comment: that is for filling the dropdown right? i have a dropdown with the select-options "1", "2" and so on. and it filters the datatable. but only the columns where there is only one conttype. if there are two conttypes (like "1 2") it doesnt recognise them. sorry if my question wasnt clear